# Dependency between wave data format and input buffer size

Tags: wave, vfw

I do some quick solution using VFW.
At the stage of preparing to receive audio data I ask VFW to give me the default wave data format for the attached WEBcam.
It returns me WAVEFORMATEX struct, pls, see the pic.

[image: pic1]

As you can see it's 1 byte for sample and 1 channel.. 11025 bytes per sec.
But the callBack receives another amount o bytes, pls, see the pic
[image: pic 2]

And the question is: what is the correlation and dependency between these to values?
How to separate data in such case if there are 2 channels?

Answer (score 0):

`dwBufferLength` is the size of the buffer, not the amount of captured bytes. You are interested in another member: [`dwBytesRecorded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd743837).

In case of stereo `WAVEFORMATEX` will have 2 in `nChannels`, and then `nBlockAlign`, `nAvgBytesPerSec` will be adjusted respectively. The bytes in the buffers will have the following packing:

```
0000: [sample 0, channel 0]
0001: [sample 0, channel 1]
0002: [sample 1, channel 0]
0003: [sample 1, channel 1]
...
```